# Sort the hash having the key as "YYYY-MM" in rails

Tags: ruby

I have an hash having the keys in the format `"YYYY-MM"`.

I want to sort the hash in the ascending order . Below is what I'd like:

```
{"2013-05" => 2 , "2013-06" => 4 , "2013-07" =>10 , ... }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
require 'Date'
my_hash = {"2013-10" => 2 , "2013-06" => 4 , "2013-07" =>10}

new_hash = Hash[my_hash.sort_by{|k,_| Date.strptime(k, '%Y-%m')}]
p new_hash # => {"2013-06"=>4, "2013-07"=>10, "2013-10"=>2}
```

Just remove then Hash[] part if you rather want the output to be an array.  You'll need to do this if using Ruby <= 1.8.7 (in older versions of Ruby, hashes have no defined order).

Edit: There are two reasons why sorting by parsing a date is preferable over just sorting the strings. The first one is validation, To check that the date-strings in the hash are actually in the correct format. The second in that it will also handle, and sort correctly, months without and a zero added. "2013-06" and "2013-6" will be treated the same, and that is not the case if you only sort using the string.

Comment: a hash has no ordering - you will have to produce an Array, but using strptime is the correct solution.

Comment: A hash do have an order in later versions of Ruby (1.9+) if i remember correctly. The sort_by converts the Hash to an array and then sorts it. More info about the change here: http://www.igvita.com/2009/02/04/ruby-19-internals-ordered-hash/

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev In ruby 2, `Hashes enumerate their values in the order that the corresponding keys were inserted.` so `sort_by` works

Comment: Is it strictly necessary to use strptime here?  YYYY-MM will sort numerically already - that's one of the benefits of ISO 8601 date formats

Comment: No it is not, but it will help you the day you get a malformed date.

Comment: Thanks for the response . But it did not work for me . Below are the 2 hash which i am displaying before and after sort .             Hash before sort {"2012-12"=>138, "2012-11"=>6, "2013-09"=>26, "2013-08"=>29, "2013-07"=>251, "2013-06"=>252, "2013-05"=>335, "2013-04"=>259, "2013-03"=>230, "2013-02"=>131, "2013-01"=>291, "2013-10"=>64}
Hash after sort {"2012-12"=>138, "2012-11"=>6, "2013-09"=>26, "2013-08"=>29, "2013-07"=>251, "2013-06"=>252, "2013-05"=>335, "2013-04"=>259, "2013-03"=>230, "2013-02"=>131, "2013-01"=>291, "2013-10"=>64}

Comment: Are you using Ruby 1.9+? The sort does not modify the hash, it creates a new one so you need to assign it to a new varibale.

Comment: I am using ruby 1.8.7 and i assigned the hash in other hash to see the result . But i get that result which i pasted above

Comment: Seems that Ruby hash by default get sorted in ruby 1.8.7. http://kartzontech.blogspot.co.il/2010/11/ordered-hashes-in-ruby.html

Comment: If you are using a ruby version prior to 1.9 I would store the final values in an array instead of a Hash, just remove the Hash[] part on the final line to get back an Array instead.

Answer (score 0):

Sort by key also works:

```
h = {"2013-10" => 2 , "2013-06" => 4 , "2012-07" =>10}

Hash[h.sort_by{|k,_| k}]
# => {"2012-07"=>10, "2013-06"=>4, "2013-10"=>2}

#which is same as h.sort

Hash[h.sort]
# => {"2012-07"=>10, "2013-06"=>4, "2013-10"=>2}
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way:

```
> h={"2013-10" => 2 , "2013-06" => 4 , "2013-07" =>10 }
=> {"2013-10"=>2, "2013-06"=>4, "2013-07"=>10}
> Hash[h.sort]
=> {"2013-06"=>4, "2013-07"=>10, "2013-10"=>2}
```